# Counting words in a rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm using the following validation to count words in rails (I got the example from the Rails docs), but it's not real accurate:

```
validates :body, :length => {
    :minimum   => 50,
    :maximum   => 300,
    :tokenizer => lambda { |str| str.scan(/\w+/) },
    :too_short => "must have at least %{count} words",
    :too_long  => "must have at most %{count} words"
  }
```

A user tried to post something that's 291 words (that's the count Word gives) and it was rejected as too long. I don't know exactly what's wrong with the expression that's being used, or what might be a good expression to ensure an accurate word count.

Comment: Did they cut-and-paste, or post plain-text? And did you count the words? That should be pretty close. You could try `/\S+/` in hopes that if there's special characters they'll just be included in the word--it's possible `/\w+/` is choking on Word's special chars (smart quotes, etc.) I suppose encoding might matter; not sure.

Comment: Yeah, it was probably a cut and paste job, but I tried plain text and it still counted 14 extra words -- he had a lot of quotes. I went with `/\b\S+\b/` and it seems to be working fairly accurately now.

Comment: It'd be interesting to follow up with what's wrong; you could create a short, known-bad string and see what `scan` actually creates--I'm not sure why it would be doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of scanning for /\w+/ you should scan for /\s+|$/ and decrease the max by one since the \w word character match can be unexpected with unusual characters since only A-Za-z0-9_- are valid.

Comment: It's worth noting that you should use the posix character property if you need this to work for stuff beyond standard ASCII characters.  Here is the regex i'm using /\p{Space}+|$/ that gives me full UTF-8 support.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
:tokenizer => lambda { |str| str.split }
```