# Rails 5 client-side validation of word count not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, client-side-validation

I am trying to validate the word count of a text area in my application.
I have tried following [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706650/counting-words-in-a-rails-validation) but i cant get mine to work.

My validation:

```
validates :skills_response, :length => {
  :minimum   => 5,
  :maximum   => 10,
  :tokenizer => lambda { |str| str.scan(/\s+|$/) },
  :too_short => "must have at least %{count} words",
  :too_long  => "must have at most %{count} words"
}
```

I am using the [client side validations gem](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations), and as you can see, the above isn't working, as it is still counting characters.

[image]

I have also tried `:tokenizer => lambda { |str| str.split }` which did not work either. Why is this happenning?

Answer (score 2):

Length counts characters not words.  If you want to check for words you can add your own custom validator to your model:

```
validate :check_for_words

def check_for_words
      if self.skills_response.split.size > 10
         errors.add(:base, "You must have less than 10 words")
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use split and count to get the number of words, then create a function to return true and false based on that.

```
2.3.3 :001 > string = "Hello World today"
 => "Hello World today" 
2.3.3 :002 > split = string.split(' ')
 => ["Hello", "World", "today"] 
2.3.3 :003 > split.count
 => 3 




validate :validation

def validation
  errors.add(:for_validation, "error") if form_field.split(' ').count < 10
end
```